# AngularUI Router change child url without parent url params

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I've got problem with create proper routing for angular app. I've decided to use `angular-ui router`, since it has nested views. Basically my app should work similar to `google graphs` site. I've got page which shows user products. Products are organized into categories so if user selects `category1` all products from this category will be listed (some teaser pictures and name as link) whith route `/category/{categoryId}`.

If user clicks product link from categories page, the url should change to `/item/{itemId}`, but the page should behave similar to google graphs: all products are sliding up and down, and product details are presented in gap between two parts.

On the other hand, if user enter `/item/{itemId}` in browser, page with another layout should be render (only product details without animation and list of products, can be served from server). When I'm using nested views from `angular-ui router` with `absolute route`s I've got problem, that parameter `categoryId` has to be added to product item route, instead `ui-sref` doesn't work:

My routing:

```
var app = angular.module('productsApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'productsControllers'
]);

app.config(["$locationProvider", function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    var urlPrefix = '/' + productsSettings.lang + '/' + productsSettings.productsName;

    $stateProvider
        .state('category', {
            url: urlPrefix + '/category/{categoryId}',
            views: {
                'products-view': {
                    templateUrl: productsSettings.hostUrl + '/Content/partials/products/products-index.html',
                    controller: 'ProductsSearchCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('category.item', {
            url: '^' + urlPrefix + '/item/{itemId}/{categoryId:(?:/[^/]+)?}',
            views: {
                'item-view' : {
                    templateUrl: productsSettings.hostUrl + '/Content/partials/products/products-item.html',
                    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
                        $scope.itemId = $stateParams.itemId;
                    }
                }
            }
    });

}]);
```

products-index.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="product in products" class="span2">

            <div class="photo">
                <img ng-src="http://placehold.it/240x240" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <!--                 <a href="/en/products/item/{{ product.KimballNumber }}">{{ product.Name }}</a>-->
                <a ui-sref="category.item({itemId: product.KimballNumber})">{{ product.Name }}</a>
            </div>

            <div class="desc2" style="height:50px;padding:10px 0;">
                <span ng-repeat="slug in product.Breadcrumb">\ {{slug}} </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ui-view="item-view"></div>
```

and partial responsible for rendering menu:

```
@model CategoriesMenuRenderingModel

@CreateCategories(Model.Categories)

@helper CreateCategories(IList<CategoryItem> categories)
{
    if (categories.Any())
    {
        <div class="sidebar-nav">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                @foreach (var category in categories)
                {
                    <li>
                        <a ui-sref="category({categoryId:'@category.Path'})">@category.DisplayName</a>
                        @CreateCategories(category.Children)
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    }
}
```

How to remove parameter `{categoryId}` from item url?

Comment: Why would you even want to remove CategoryId from url? Without CategoryId - ItemId does not make sense, right? CategoryId from the app logic must be part of url (state). I would even say /category/categoryId/item/itemId ... is the url, your users can take and share with others...

Comment: Bussiness requirements. Url for product must be /item/{itemID}

Comment: Having categoryId included in productId on ecommerce sites is not a good idea. URL should be constant, while categorisation may change, category name can change and products sometimes may be contained in more than one category.